# How to check if LVALUE represents SCALAR

Tags: perl

For years, I am using a code that contains the following condition

```
ref \$_[0] eq 'SCALAR'
```

I always expect there an `ARRAY` or `SCALAR`, but recently I passed `substr()` into that parameter. Unexpected things happened. The condition returned a false value.

Then I figured it out. The `ref` returned `LVALUE` instead of `SCALAR`.

Since `LVALUE` is a weird type of reference, I need to check if a scalar is behind it.

How can I check is this `LVALUE` represents `SCALAR` or not?

Comment: `$_[0]` is always a scalar, and `ref \$_[0]` will never be `ARRAY` (unless you do something like `my $x; bless(\$x, "ARRAY"); f($x)`).

Comment: Yes, King @ikegami – as you realized, your "never" is **NOT** never. Therefore, it is better checked :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An LVALUE is a special magical value that takes action when it is assigned to. So for example, calling `f($hash{foo})` doesn't immediately create the foo entry in %hash; instead a temporary LVALUE is created and passed to the sub as `$_[0]`. If `$_[0]` is subsequently assigned to, that value gets stored as `$hash{foo}`.

An LVALUE is a scalar (i.e. it holds a single value), just an odd type of scalar.

So it's likely that the code can be fixed by just accepting both SCALAR and LVALUE as valid values. But it will depend on exactly why the check is done. It may also be that such a check is a logic error and is not actually needed, or is buggy. For example `ref \$_[0]` should never return ARRAY.

Comment: Ah, you explained it better than I did. This does have all the hallmarks of an XY problem I think.

Comment: All I needed to hear is here :)

Answer (score 2):

Values that can be returned by `reftype( $x )` (from Scalar::Util) in Perl 5.36:

| Value | Description | Can be dereferenced? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `undef` | The value of `$x` isn't a reference. | No |
| `"ARRAY"` | `$x` reference an array (a scalar of type PVAV. | As an array |
| `"HASH"` | `$x` reference a hash (a scalar of type PVHV). | As a hash |
| `"CODE"` | `$x` reference a sub (a scalar of type PVCV). | As a sub |
| `"GLOB"` | `$x` reference a glob (a scalar of type PVGV). | As a glob, scalar, array, hash or code |
| `"LVALUE"` | `$x` references a scalar of type PVLV, with some exceptions. | As a scalar |
| `"REGEXP"` | `$x` references a scalar that's a compiled regexp pattern (a scalar of type REGEXP). | As a scalar |
| `"IO"` | `$x` references a scalar that's an IO object (a scalar of type PVIO). | No |
| `"FORMAT"` | `$x` references a scalar of type PVFM. I don't know if it's possible to get a reference to a format. | No |
| `"INVLIST"` | `$x` references a scalar of type INVLIST. This is an internal type. You should never see this. | No |
| `"REF"` | `$x` references a scalar that contains a reference. | As a scalar |
| `"VSTRING"` | `$x` references a scalar that contains a version string. | As a scalar |
| `"SCALAR"` | `$x` references something else. | As a scalar |

Exceptions:

- `SCALAR` is returned for reference to a tied PVLV.
- `REF` is returned for reference to a PVLV containing a reference.

Warnings:

- `REF` is returned for magical variables that currently contain a reference, and `SCALAR` for those that don't. But the value of magical variables can change every time you fetch it.

---

`ref( $x )` is similar. It returns `false` (the special scalar, not the string `false`) instead of `undef` if the value of `$x` isn't a reference. If `$x` is a reference to something blessed, it returns the package into which it is blessed. Otherwise, it returns the same as `reftype( $x )`. I consider `ref` a broken mix of `reftype` and `blessed`.

---

> I always expect there an `ARRAY` or `SCALAR`

`reftype( \$_[0] )` will never be `ARRAY`.

`ref( \$_[0] )` can return `ARRAY`, but only if you do something weird like `my $x; bless( \$x, "ARRAY" ); f( $x )`. (And that's why I consider it broken.)

`$_[0]` is always going to a scalar. Array elements can only be scalars. Arguments can only be scalars.

> How can I check is this `LVALUE` represents `SCALAR` or not?

It's always a scalar.

In your case, you don't need `reftype` or `ref` to tell you that. The value of array elements are always scalars, so `$_[0]` is always going to be a scalar.

As per above, it's returned for scalars of type PVLV. It's a type of magical scalar. Most magical scalars are of type PVMG, but some types of magic take advantage of the extra fields provided by a PVLV scalar. PVLV scalars are returned by `$h{EXPR}` as an argument, `pos` as lvalue, `substr` as lvalue, `vec` as lvalue, and more.